# How to use regex to find variable name beginning with @ in a string expression?

Tags: c#, regex

The programmer hope to get two variables day1 and day2 by using regex, all the other variables in string expression beginning with the character `@` too.

The example of a string expression: `@day1 - @day2 > 3`

Thanks!

Comment: @Charlieface Maybe not.  Putting `\b` before `@` will never match a preceding whitespace, as whitespace and `@` are both non word characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use positive lookahead here.

```
string = "@day1 - @day2 > 3";
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=@)\\w+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var match = regex.Matches(a);
foreach( var val in match )
{
   Console.WriteLine(val);
}
```

val contains the match values.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lookbehind to get the variable names, like so:

```
var regex = new Regex("(?<=@)\\w+");
```

This will get the words preceded by an @ sign